# Platform independent xaringan presentation (Blackboard)

Tags: r, rstudio, xaringan

I'm preparing some html slides for my students. I have used both `slidy` and `ioslides` before and basically I can upload those straight onto Blackboard within an `iframe` box without any problems.

I've just started playing with `xaringan` and it looks like I loose the fonts and styles and some of the images (for example `knitr` output) after uploading to Blackboard.

Here is an example of the "Ninja" template in R Studio:

a) this is how it should look like

[image]

b) this is how it looks like after uploading to Blackboard

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/some-tips.html#disadvantages (and I recommend you to use a true web server, such as Netlify to host your slides).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into this

Comment: @YihuiXie so I basically bundle the css, libraries and html (renamed to index.html) together in a folder and deploy on Netlify? I've included all images (R output etc.) in the folder, but they are not showing up yet.

Comment: R output fixed with `dev="svg"` setting in `knitr` chunk - just need to get external images to work now

Comment: you don't need to use `dev="svg"`, I have a little repo to demonstrate how to host xaringan on gh-pages if you are interested: [repo](https://github.com/tcgriffith/xaringan_gh) [webpage](https://tcgriffith.github.io/xaringan_gh/), netlify should be similar

Comment: @TCZhang cool, will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I came up with

- css, styles and index.html (rename your Rmd slide to index.Rmd is the easiest) need to be hosted on true web server, i.e. Github or Netlify

  - if you use Github: enable github pages settings
- the image output in the R chunk needs to be set to `dev="svg"`

I'm still having problems with including other images though.